# NoErrorObjectAvailable only on iOS devices using chrome

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am developing a public site in which I used a visual force to load a LWC throughout an Aura Component. When I use the site on desktop and on android devices I not receive any problems. But when I am using it on iOS (using chrome, not with safary) devices and I interact with some object in the page, for instance an input or a check box, I get an error at the bottom of the page ("This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error"). Someone has some idea to fix this problem? Since I noticed the problem I was not able to solve the problem.

Just for information the LWC use the classi HTML markup with a css style sheet loaded in the visualforce.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is the chrome version same?